# What kind of space character is this?

Tags: sed, regex

This is pretty weird, using a .txt document sent by a friend using Windows, I believe I have found a weird space character.

If I run `cat file` the character appears as ��

Also, I was running `if [[ " " = " " ]] ; then echo yes ; fi` and it was not giving me a success code. (The character loses it's property once on Stack Exchange, so running it will give you a success code)

**Edit**
The file was in iso-8859-1 and not utf-8 encoding.

Using Serg's solution, I was able to convert it to utf-8

Comment: Copied. Printed yes.

Comment: Darn, the character must have been converted once posted to stackexchange.

Comment: Can't reproduce..run `cat -e file` and see what it shows..

Comment: @TuxForLife what does `file -i filename` tell you about encoding ?

Comment: Running cat -e file displays the spaces as:
`M- ^M$`

Comment: file -i file outputs `text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: @TuxForLife try changing the encoding to us-ascii or utf-8. Guide here: http://www.shellhacks.com/en/HowTo-Determine-and-Change-File-Character-Encoding

Comment: Run `echo -n ' ' | hexdump` and post the output (of course replace the space between the single quotes with the character)

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use `dos2unix`..use `dos2unix -n file file.out`..now check `file.out` .....if not installed already: `sudo apt-get install dos2unix`

Comment: Using Serg's guide, running `iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 file > output` did the trick.
Thanks guys, specifically the 3 of you are favorite and most helpful askubuntu users >.<

Comment: So I guess we can post an answer and call it a day

Comment: @Serg You should post the answer, anyway @ OP if you drop me a comment with the last four-digit number on the first line of the `echo` / `hexdump` command suggest above I'll post a `sed` solution as well

Comment: I'm interested in that solution suggested by kos !  @TuxForLife do you still have the original file ?

Comment: @kos the 4 digits of the hexdump output of the weird space character: a0c2

Comment: Entire ouput is `0000000 a0c2                                   
0000002` vs. `0000000 0020                                   
0000001` (Normal space)

Comment: Hmmm weird. That is (judging from [your `echo -n '<character>' | hexdump` output](http://askubuntu.com/questions/633938/what-kind-of-space-character-is-this#comment904001_633938)) the Unicode character ["Yi Syllable Me"](http://unicode-table.com/en/A0C2/) (`U+A0C2`), which should not being read well in the current document encoding (as it's happening, being ISO-8859-1 a subset of Unicode) but that should be read well once converted to UTF-8.

Comment: Also I rolled back your edits in order to preserve the question / answers format of the site, it should be really kept like that. Can you please roll back to your last updated version of the question?

Comment: It wasn't letting me revert it back to my old question, so I didn't remember it word for word, but I tried to include new and old, since no one is able to reproduce the if statement. Do you think it may be due to the fact I copied the character from the gedit text editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the file encoding has been reported as `iso-8859-1` , you can convert the encoding of a file using `iconv -f old-encoding -t new-encoding inputfile > outputfile`

More info: http://www.shellhacks.com/en/HowTo-Determine-and-Change-File-Character-Encoding

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dos2unix`. From `man dos2unix`:

```
dos2unix - DOS/Mac to Unix and vice versa text file format converter
```

For example you can do:

```
dos2unix -n file.in file.out
```

Now `file.out` will be in UNIX format. `dos2unix` can convert windows line endings and encodings to UNIX format so you can use it for both cases. If it is not installed you can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

Comment: Cool, this does the exact same as iconv doesn't it? The only reason I went with the iconv method is because iconv already comes installed in my setup (Linux Mint 17). But if I ever need this alternative for the future, or some other user needs it, this post will greatly help!

Comment: `dos2unix` seems simpler to me as it finds what needs to be done and acts accordingly..you just need to sit back and watch  :)

Answer (score 1):

A guess I have is the line endings.

Windows uses `\r\n` while *UNIX uses `\n`.

Probably what you are seeing are the `\r` characters, since they have no meaning for *UNIX.

There's no problem opening a text file on Windows with `\n` endings, since Windows converts it automatically to `\r\n` (only in Text mode), while *UNIX doesn't have such feature.

Comment: Is this related to kasperd's answer? I was getting what he mentioned, but perhaps they are the same thing?

Comment: @TuxForLife They are related, but not the same. This only talks about the line endings, that one talks about a solution to other problems.

Answer (score 1):

The character you are seeing sounds like a non-breaking space. It is character number 160 in iso-8859-1 and unicode. In some keyboard layouts it can be entered using <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>. If you view the file with `cat -e` it will be displayed as `M-` as in this example:

```
$ printf '\xa0\n' | cat -e
M- $
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was getting!